# Variance of the integral of a stochastic process

Tags: variance, stochastic-processes, linear, integral

I understand the discete case i.e. the sum of $N$ identically distributed random variables $X_i$ with variance $\sigma^2$. The correlation between these random variables is given by the correlation matrix $\mathbf{\rho}(X_i,X_j)$.

The variance of the linear combination of random variables $X_i$ is given by:

$$\operatorname{Var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right) = N\sigma^2+2\sigma^2\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}\mathbf{\rho}(X_i,X_j)$$

Source: [Wikipedia - Variance - Sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables)

I would like to consider the continuous case of a stochastic process which will be denoted as $X(t)$. The process is stationary with constant variance $\sigma^2$ and correlation function $\rho(X(t),X(h)$. Similar to above I would like to calculate the variance of the linear combination of the random variables $X(t)$. I think that the linear combination over some domain $t \in [0,L]$ can be expressed as

$$I = \int_0^L X(t) dt$$

I would like to know the variance of $I$:

$$\operatorname{Var}(I)=?$$

I speculate that if the process $Z(X_i)$ is completely correlated i.e. $\rho(X(t),X(h)) = 1$ then the variance of $I$ is <s>minimised</s> maximised and is given by:
$$\operatorname{Var}(I)=L^2\sigma^2$$

If the variables are uncorrelated i.e. $\rho(X(t),X(h))=0$ then I suspect that the variance of $I$ is <s>maximised</s> minimised. It may be <s>infinite</s> zero?

I find the continuous case (i.e. infinite random variables over some domain [0,L]) difficult to understand. Could anyone provide me an expression for the variance of $I$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interchanging the order of integration and expectation you get
$$E(I)=E\int_0^L X(t) dt = \int_0^L EX(t) dt = \int_0^L \mu dt = L\mu $$
and similarly, the second moment of $I$ becomes
\begin{align}
E(I^2)&=E\left(\int_0^LX(t)dt\int_0^LX(u)du\right) \\
&= E \int_0^L \int_0^L X(t)X(u)du dt \\
&= \int_0^L \int_0^L E[X(t)X(u)]du dt \\
&= \int_0^L \int_0^L [\operatorname{Cov}(X(t),X(u))+EX(t)EX(u)] du dt \\
&= \sigma^2 \int_0^L \int_0^L \rho(t-u)dudt + L^2 \mu^2.
\end{align}
If the correlation function $\rho(h)$ is for example exponential the double intergral can be easily solved.  The variance of $I$ can be found from the general formula $\operatorname{Var}I =E(I^2)-(EI)^2$.

Comment: Excellent. This makes sense to me. I will try to verify this with simulation.

Comment: This assumes that the process is wide-sense stationary or weakly stationary. Also, for this special case, the double integral simplifies to a single integral $$\int_{-L}^{L} \rho(s)(L-|s|)\,\mathrm ds$$ which is easier to work with.

Comment: Good comment. Integration using Wolfram Mathematica gives the same result using both expressions for  $$\rho(s) = \exp\left(-\pi\left(\frac{s}{\theta}\right)^2\right)$$ Is it correct that your expression works for all isotropic correlation functions i.e. $s = |t - u|$? Could you explain how you got to your expression? My understanding of double integrals is poor.

Comment: Even if unrelated to the question itself, I find a little confusing the statement $\text{Var}[I]=\text{E}[I^2]-\text{E}[I]^2$ as a consequence of the exponential correlation. Isn't it true for any random variable?

Comment: @RiccardoBuscicchio Yes