# Find the Variance of random variable $Y=\int_{0}^{2}X(t)dt $

Tags: self-study, variance, random-variable

> If $X(t)$ is stationary process having mean value $E[X(t)]=3$ and autocorrelation function $R_{xx}(\tau)=9+2e^{-|\tau|}$.The variance of random variable $Y=\int_{0}^{2}X(t)dt $ will be____
>
> $(A)1$
>
> $(B)2.31$
>
> $(C)4.54$
>
> $(D)0$

---

I have no idea how to solve this but I tried like this

---

$$E[X^2]=R_{xx}(0)=11$$
$$E[X]^2=9$$

\begin{align}
Var(Y)&=\int_{0}^{2}Var(X(t))dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}E[X^2(t)]-E[X]^2dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}2dt\\
&=4
\end{align}

But its not in the options.

Comment: There doesn't exist any such process unless "autocorrelation" is replaced by "autocovariance."  That's because the size of the autocorrelation cannot exceed $1$, whereas $R$ obviously gets much larger than that.  Another clue that $R$ cannot be autocorrelation is that the mean and autocorrelation alone do not determine the variance of any function of $X$ that depends on its scale--and that obviously includes $Y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: The error of your approach was to pull out the integral from the Variance function. While this works (under some conditions) for the expected value, it doesn't for $$E\left[\left(\int_0^2X(t)dt\right)^2\right],$$ due to the square term.

Note that:

- You can calculate $E[Y]$ by interchanging integration and expected value.
- $E[Y]^2$ can be calculated by using \begin{align}E[Y^2]&=E\left[\left(\int_0^2X(t)dt\right)\left(\int_0^2X(s)ds\right)\right]\\
  &=\int_0^2\int_0^2E[X(t)X(s)]dt~ds\\
  &=\int_0^2\int_0^2R(t-s)dt~ds\\
  &\left(=\int_{-2}^2(2-|x|)R(x)dx\right)
  \end{align}

Altogether, this should yield answer $(C)$.

**EDIT:** I used the identity
$$\int_0^a\int_0^a f(x-y) dx~dy =\int_{-a}^a (a-|z|)f(z) dz$$
for the last part ([Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8bMB.gif)), but it's not needed. You can also directly calculate the double integral. Just split it into a positive and negative part, in order to get rid of the absolute term in the exponent.  After that it's plain calculation.

**EDIT2:** Note that
\begin{align}
\int_0^2\int_0^2R(t-s)dt~ds&=\int_0^2\int_0^2 9+2\exp^{-|t-s|}dt~ds\\
&=36+2\int_0^2\int_0^2\exp^{-|t-s|}dt~ds\\
&=36+2\left(\int_0^2\int_s^2\exp^{-(t-s)}dt~ds+\int_0^2\int_0^s\exp^{t-s}dt~ds\right).
\end{align}

Comment: @Eldioo Can you help me how did you change from this integration $$\int_0^2\int_0^2R(t-s)dt~ds$$ to this integration please.
$$\int_{-2}^2(2-|x|)R(x)dx$$

Comment: @Xi'an did'nt get you ? should I ask another question for this?

Comment: @Rohit If you don't know how to calculate the double integral, check my edit. Does that clear things up or do you want another hint?

Comment: @Eldioo can you do it with the double integral without the identity I am not getting how to do at the last part.

Comment: @Eldioo Can you provide me any link for that identity of integration please

Comment: No problem, just included the proof in a picture (see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8bMB.gif)). Basically, you substitute $x-y$ and then split up the integral, in order to interchange the integration order, which gets rid of one of the integrals.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint #1:** The equality
$$Var(Y)=\int_{0}^{2}Var(X(t))dt$$
is incorrect

**Hint #2:** If you are unfamiliar with continuous time process, try to use first a (Riemann) discretisation of the integral.

**Hint #3:** this question has [already been asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226674/7224) on X validated.