# Variance of integral of Poisson variables

Tags: variance, stochastic-processes

I have a stochastic quantity (not sure if it is a proper stochastic process), defined as follows:

$$I = \int d x f(x) X(x)$$
$f(x)$ is a positive function of real variable, defined over the integral domain.
$X(x)$ is a sequence of random variables, defined over $x$ as their parameter space.

In particular, their are uncorrelated, Poisson distributed, with means and variances equal to $\mu_{X}(x)$.
I'm interested in the mean and variance of $I$.

Using the first and second order moments I get

$$
\text{E}[I] = \text{E}\left[\int d x f(x) X(x)\right]=\int d x f(x)\mu_{X}(x)
$$
and 
\begin{align}
\text{E}[I^2] =& \text{E}\left[\int d x f(x) X(x)\int d y f(y) X(y)\right] \\
=& \int d x d y f(x) f(y) \text{E}\left[X(x)X(y)\right] \\
=& \int d x d y f(x) f(y) \delta(x-y)\text{E}\left[X(x)^2\right]\\
=& \int d x f(x)^2 \text{E}\left[X(x)^2\right]\\
=& \int d x f(x)^2 \text{Var}\left[X(x)\right] + \text{E}\left[X(x)\right]^2 \\
=&  \int d x f(x)^2  (\mu_{X}(x) +\mu_{X}(x)^2)
\end{align}
Although the variance of $I$

\begin{align}
\text{Var}[I] =& \text{E}[I^2]-\text{E}[I]^2 \\
=& \int d x f(x)^2  (\mu_{X}(x) +\mu_{X}(x)^2)- \left(\int d x f(x)\mu_{X}(x)\right)^2
\end{align}
is not necessarily positive.

Consider, e.g. $f(x) = 1$, $\mu_{X}(x)=x$, and $I$ to be defined over $[1,3]$

\begin{align}
\text{Var}[I]
=& \int_1^3 d x (x+x^2)- \left(\int_1^3 d x x\right)^2\\
=& - \frac{10}{3}
\end{align}
Any help figuring out the issue would be appreciated. A somewhat related answer is
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226674/257725) although it actually goes in the same direction as my conclusion.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's meant by $\delta$ here. I agree with everything before that line and disagree with the following line, so I think that's where the mistake is.

Comment: @JoeMansley, thanks for your request of clarification.
The random variables defined by X(x) are uncorrelated, so the joint expectectation value in the last line you agree with is non-zero only when the two integration variables take the same value (i.e. x=y). That's why I am using in the first line you disagree with a Dirac delta for x-y and replacing the joint expectation value with the second order moment of X(x). 
Do you still disagree with my derivation?

Comment: I don't agree that the joint expectation is necessarily $0$ when $x\neq y$

Comment: I may have been unclearin my question: I assume that the sequence variables X(x), are uncorrelated, which if I am not mistaken means by definition:

$$ x \neq y \Rightarrow E[X(x) X(y)] = 0 $$

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. That they are uncorrelated means: $x \neq y \Rightarrow E[X(x)X(y)]=E[X(x)]E[X(y)]$

Comment: That's right. It was a silly mistake, confusing the correlation with the joint expectation value. I'll write an answer with a correct derivation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JoeMansley, the derivation was flawed. Here follows what I believe is the correct one, and doesn't lead to incorrect results (i.e. a negative variance).

\begin{align}
\text{E}[I^2] =& \text{E}\left[\int d x f(x) X(x)\int d y f(y) X(y)\right] \\
=& \int d x d y f(x) f(y) \text{E}\left[X(x)X(y)\right] \\
=& \left(\int d x f(x) \mu_{X}(x)\right)^2 + \int d x f(x)^2 \text{Var} \left[X(x)^2\right]\\
=& E\left[I\right]^2 + \int d x f(x)^2 \text{Var}\left[X(x)\right]
\end{align}

Therefore the variance of $I$ reads:

$$\sigma^2_I = \int d x f(x)^2 \sigma_X^2(x) $$

and for the special case at hand of Poisson, uncorrelated variables, I have:

$$\sigma^2_I = \int d x f(x)^2 \mu_X(x)^2$$

which is a generalized result to an infinite sum of uncorrelated variables of

$$\sigma^2_{aX+bY} = a^2\sigma^2_X + b^2 \sigma_Y^2$$